# jQuery get attr title piece

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="entry-content">
  <div class="vote gensmall">
  <div class="vote-bar" title="Message reputation : 100% (1 vote)">
<div class="vote-bar-plus" style="height:50px;">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

As you can see above the div witht he class `.vote-bar` I am trying to get the title, just a piece of it though. I just want the `1 vote` and that is it. Basically I am doing this to get how many votes the person has and it changes in the title of the this div.

I tried using

```
$('.vote-bar').attr('title',function(){
//function of title
});
```

More like, thats how far I've gotten, and I am not even sure where else to go now. or if I did the function correctly. I am still still learning and I am asking for help. I've searched through all the items and could not find what exactly I needed. I can call a jQuery code to pass if the title is `so forth and so forth` but I have barely used `.attr()`

Comment: This is a _very_ basic question. Why don't you [read the API docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [play around](http://jsfiddle.net/k2XmT/) and see how far you get?

Comment: @MattBall I've checked the API docs for a while now, from seeing the below answers, I would need to learn split :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.vote-bar').each( function() {
    var s = $(this).attr('title');
    var g = s.split("("); 
    var n = g[1]; 
    var m = n.replace(")", "");
    $(this).children(".vote-bar-plus").html(m);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ayjtY/1/

Comment: You have an alert function. How would I get it so it isn't an alert and placed inside a div and/or span

Comment: in fiddle there is each function which collects votes from all .vote-bar div instead just see my edited answer!

Comment: no I understand, I just don't want an alert. I want something like so EDIT: better understanding here http://jsfiddle.net/ayjtY/4/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21169/discussion-between-user1760670-and-aspiring-aqib)

Answer (score 2):

`attr()` returns a string. You can treat it as such and regex out the part you want.

```
parseInt(($('.vote-bar').attr('title').match(/\d+(?= vote)/) || ["0"])[0],10);
```

Comment: man if i have knowledge to make regex i should have done with it! bTW its good!

Comment: yeah regex I am clueless on :( can I ask what the bits and pieces mean please? Just so I can learn and understand what I am using here.

Comment: @Kolink he is asking from you!

Comment: thank you @AspiringAqib though I see your answer, and it seems to work. I tried this in a fiddle and I had no results...

Comment: if you feel uncomfortable with this answer you can go with my one but this is best approach to use regex as @Kolink have...

Comment: Basically, `\d+` means "one or more digits". The `(?=.....)` means "this part must follow, but it not a part of the match" and the ` vote` inside is literally looking for that string. So, the whole thing means "one or more digits, followed by the word `vote`". In this case, it's what you're looking for. Then, the `||["0"]` bit makes it fall back to zero if no match is found in the string. Finally, a `parseInt` ensures you get a number, not a string containing a number.

Answer (score 0):

I think this way you can take the desire result:  **http://jsfiddle.net/UCaeE/1/**

```
$('.vote-bar').each( function() {
    var Title = $(this).attr('title');
    var newTitle = Title.substr(0, Title.indexOf(')')); 
    var finalTitle = newTitle.substr(newTitle.indexOf('(')+1);
    $(this).children(".vote-bar-plus").html(finalTitle);
});
```